# Discord.py bot not sending embeds properly

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a top 10 leaderboard for my server. Since there seems to be a limit on how many fields you can add and send in one embed, I divided the scoreboard. However, my program only seems to send one embed properly as seen in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwuRo.png).(the if statement was False in this image)

There is no error message in the console.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = "**Leaderboard**", description = "Top 5")
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url)

    embed.add_field(name = "Users", value = f"{user1}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "Beans", value = f"{bean1}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user2}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean2}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user3}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean3}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user4}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean4}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user5}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean5}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    embed2 = discord.Embed(title = "**Leaderboard**", description = "Top 10")
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url)

    embed.add_field(name = "Users", value = f"{user6}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "Beans", value = f"{bean6}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user7}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean7}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user8}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user8}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user9}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean9}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user10}", inline = True) 
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean10}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)

    time.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed2)

    if leaderid not in {user001,user002,user003,user004,user005,user006,user007,user008,user009,user010}:
        embed3 = discord.Embed(title = "**Leaderboard**", description = "Your ranking")
        embed.set_footer(icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url)

        embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{user00}", inline = True)
        embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = f"{bean00}", inline = True)
        embed.add_field(name = "\u200b", value = "\u200b", inline = False)

        time.sleep(1)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create and send `embed2`, but only ever modify `embed`.  You need to modify `embed2` instead

```
embed2 = discord.Embed(title = "**Leaderboard**", description = "Top 10")
embed2.set_footer(icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url)

embed2.add_field(name = "Users", value = f"{user6}", inline = True)
embed2.add_field(name = "Beans", value = f"{bean6}", inline = True)
...
```

Comment: I see, thank you. Since I copy pasted a lot of the code, I must have missed it.